# Mapbox Android: Zoom over specific route

Tags: android, mapbox

I would like to center the calculated navigation route into the given layout for my map view. I try to do this with bounds, but the route isn't centered. Is there any other way provided so far?

```
private fun animateCamera(){
        val bounds = LatLngBounds.Builder()
                .include(LatLng(originPoint.latitude(), originPoint.longitude())) // Northeast
                .include(LatLng(destinationPoint.latitude(), destinationPoint.longitude())) // Southwest
                .build()
        map.easeCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, 100), 5000)
}
```

[image: Map Image]

Answer (score 1):

I think a better option here would be `MapboxMap#getCameraForLatLngBounds(LatLngBounds latLngBounds, int[] padding)`.  This method is aware of the current state of the map, providing a more accurate `CameraPosition`.  So with your code:

```
private fun animateCamera() {
  val bounds = LatLngBounds.Builder()
            .include(LatLng(originPoint.latitude(), originPoint.longitude())) // Northeast
            .include(LatLng(destinationPoint.latitude(), destinationPoint.longitude())) // Southwest
            .build()

  // zero padding
  val cameraPosition = map.getCameraForLatLngBounds(bounds, intArrayOf(0, 0, 0, 0))
  mapboxMap.easeCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition), 5000)
}
```